# Which data types for genetic algorithms in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, genetic-algorithm

I am implementing a GA in Python and need to store a sequence of ones and zeros, so I am representing my data as binaries. What is the best data structure for that? A simple string?

Comment: A `long` or a list of `int`s sounds more sensible.

Comment: Is it easy to perform operations like mutations or recombinations on that? Is working with lists efficient enough?

Comment: I was just responding to the "store a sequence of ones and zeroes"  part :) Maybe if you need arbitrary insertion/removal of bits, you should instead use a linked list (`collections.deque`). Can you write some info on the required operations for your data structure? This might be helpful to people like me who know Python and the available data structures, but don't know anything about genetics :)

Answer (score 5):

If your chromosomes are fixed-length bitstrings, consider using [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays and vectorized operations on them instead of lists. These may be much faster than Python lists. E.g., one-point crossover can be done with

```
def crossover(a, b):
    """Return new individual by combining parents a and b
       with random crossover point"""
    c = np.empty(a.shape, dtype=bool)
    k = np.random.randint(a.shape[0])
    c[:k] = a[:k]
    c[k:] = b[k:]
    return c
```

If you don't want to use Numpy, then strings seem quite appropriate; they're much more compact than lists, which store pointers to elements rather than actual elements.

Finally, be sure to have a look at how [Pyevolve](https://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/) represents chromosomes; it seems to do so with using Numpy.

Comment: There is also [DEAP](http://deap.googlecode.com) and [ecspy](http://ecspy.googlecode.com) which have the advantage of still being actively developed.

Answer (score 0):

I think sticking with the strings is a good idea.  You can easily chop strings into pieces.  if you need to act on them as a list, you can convert it with "list(str)".  Once you have a list, you can alter it and turn it back into a string using "''.join(lst)".

Personally, I wouldn't use a long or another integer type to store as bits.  It may be more space efficient, but the headache of working with the data when you want to do a recombination would be considerable.  Mutations would be problematic as well if the mutation consist of something other than a bit flip.  Plus, the code would be much harder to read.

Just my 2 cents.  Hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray).
Or you can play with [buffers](http://docs.python.org/dev/c-api/buffer.html).